# Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, gmail

I am trying to use the features from Google to create a GMail login system but when I tried to sync the project I got this error

```
  Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0
```

These are the edited sections I made 
Project:MarkRecorder

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'**
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and   Module:app

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the correct version of the Play Services library dependency you are using before you compile your project. You can do this through the SDK manager bundled with Android Studio.

From developers.google.com:

```
1. Start Android Studio.
2. On the Tools menu, click Android > SDK Manager.
3. Update the Android Studio SDK Manager: click SDK Tools, expand Support Repository, select Google Repository, and then click OK.
```

The current version of Google Play Services is 10.2.0, so you might need to go back and manually download 9.8.0 (unless you are willing to upgrade). Check [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more info.